# Regular expression to remove <br> from <pre>

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to remove the `<br />` tags that appear in between the `<pre></pre>` tags. My string looks like

```
string str = "Test<br/><pre><br/>Test<br/></pre><br/>Test<br/>---<br/>Test<br/><pre><br/>Test<br/></pre><br/>Test"

string temp = "`##`";
while (Regex.IsMatch(result, @"\<pre\>(.*?)\<br\>(.*?)\</pre\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, @"\<pre\>(.*?)\<br\>(.*?)\</pre\>", "<pre>$1" + temp + "$2</pre>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
str = str.Replace(temp, System.Environment.NewLine);
```

But this replaces all <`br>` tags between first and the last `<pre>` in the whole text. Thus my final outcome is:

```
str = "Test<br/><pre>\r\nTest\r\n</pre>\r\nTest\r\n---\r\nTest\r\n<pre>\r\nTest\r\n</pre><br/>Test"
```

I expect my outcome to be

```
str = "Test<br/><pre>\r\nTest\r\n</pre><br/>Test<br/>---<br/>Test<br/><pre>\r\nTest\r\n</pre><br/>Test"
```

Comment: Is the format of the string always the same, that is, is it regular? Or are you trying to get this out of whole HTML pages that might be in completely different structures?

Comment: *sigh* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: There's a lot of wisdom that regex and html are **not** good friends. It might work for some *limited* scenarios, but personally I'd be using a parser/DOM/whatever here.

Comment: ok, so if I agree that parsing html with regex is not a good option. so then is it that the regex will only parse tags between first and last `<pre>` tags?

Comment: how can "\<br\>" match "<br/>"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I discovered the issue with my code. The problem was that, Regex.IsMatch was considering just the first occurrence of `<pre>` and the last occurrence of `</pre>`. I wanted to consider individual sets of `<pre>` for replacements. So I modified my code as

```
foreach (Match regExp in Regex.Matches(str, @"\<pre\>(.*?)\<br\>(.*?)\</pre\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
{
    matchFound = true;
    str = str.Replace(regExp.Value, regExp.Value.Replace("<br>", temp));
}
```

and it worked well. Anyways thanks all for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

If you are parsing whole HTML pages, RegEx is not a good choice - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a good demonstration of why.

Use an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this kind of work. It also works with fragments like the one you posted.

Comment: I am just trying to parse the above string that i mentioned in str.

Comment: That is not answer for the question. That guy asked for regex and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to do it.

"Be lazy, use CPAN and use HTML::Sanitizer." -Jeff Atwood, [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
        string input = "Test<br/><pre><br/>Test<br/></pre><br/>Test<br/>---<br/>Test<br/><pre><br/>Test<br/></pre><br/>Test";
        string pattern = @"<pre>(.*)<br/>(([^<][^/][^p][^r][^e][^>])*)</pre>";
        while (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
        {
            input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "<pre>$1\r\n$2</pre>");
        }
```

this will probably work, but you should use html agility pack, this will not match `<br>` or `<br />` etc.